# Magento : Customer Grid Ajax Breaking

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I recently upgraded a Magento to v1.7.0.2 from Magento connect. Now everything seems to work fine except that the Manage Customer grid in the admin breaks when trying to sort or navigate to other page.

So what I have realized is that we get a blank response in the ajax that is responsible to load the customer grid.

Apart from the customer grid, we have checked all the other grids seem to be working fine. Please let me know if further details are required.

Comment: What version of Magento did you upgrade from and how heavily customised is your store?

Comment: I upgraded from 1.6.2 and and the admin is not customized at all.

Comment: Ok, not a massive change from 1.6.2.0 then.  Is every aspect of the store working correctly after the upgrade apart from this grid (from what you have found so far)?  I only ask because upgrades are very often not as simple as just running it and everything works.

Comment: Well everything seems to be working fine now, except this.